# How to export data for a manual read?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some columns with data as large as 8000 characters. For some of the records in my table, I wanted to export this information into a text file so that I can manually go through some records. So essentially I have a table like this:

```
Col1  | Col2  | Col3
---------------------
 A1   |   A2  |   A3
 B1   |   B2  |   B3
```

which I want to format into the following form and write into a text file:

```
Col1:
A1
Col2:
A2
Col3:
A3

Col1:
B1
Col2:
B2
Col3:
B3
```

Can someone please suggest a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'Col1:' + char(13) + Char(10) + Col1 + char(13) + Char(10)
     + 'Col2:' + char(13) + Char(10) + Col2 + char(13) + Char(10)
     + 'Col3:' + char(13) + Char(10) + Col3 + char(13) + Char(10)
     + char(13) + Char(10)
from table
```

EDIT: And you have to make sure you have selected 'Results to Text' instead of 'Results to grid' in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: +1 Thank You. `char(13)` is meant to give me a new line but it does not seem to give me one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try char(13) + char(10) for crlf

Comment: Have you selected 'Results to Text' in SSMS ?

Comment: The Char(13) + Char(10) worked. Thanks a lot to you and @Alex K for your time.